# Set back color of DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I used this code snippet

```
// Second Column: Hand to use
DataGridViewComboBoxCell handToUseCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this._robotSelectionDataGridView[Common.SECOND_COLUMN, currentRow];
handToUseCell.Items.Clear();
foreach (Hand hand in robotInfo.Hands)
{
  handToUseCell.Items.Add(hand.Name.ToString());
}
handToUseCell.DisplayStyle = (handToUseCell.Items.Count > 1) ? DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox :
                                                    DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
handToUseCell.Value = handToUseCell.Items[0];
handToUseCell.Style.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
```

But back color not changed. What happens when I set cell.style.backcolor?

Comment: Are you trying to set the back color for the dropdown or the element (shown) it self..??

Comment: I tried to add backcolor to dropdown.

Comment: @Vidhya are you trying in windows application

Answer (score 0):

Try followings

`handToUseCell.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;`

or

`handToUseCell.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;`

Let me know the results..
Hope it helps.

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxCell dont have "DefaultCellStyle" and "CellStyle" properties.

Comment: try referring this documentation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/z2akwyy7.aspx let me know whether it helps or not..